# Should you have an index action for view controllers?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

For a lot of my view controllers, I do not have an index action. Is this bad practice?

After looking through a lot of sample applications I see that almost all applications that don't use an index action, at-least declare the following:

```
public function action_index()
{
    $this->request->redirect('');
}
```

Is it best practice to at-least have this index redirect for each view controller or is it perfectly acceptable to not even declare such method as I am currently doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare action_index method.
Simply set default action for route to something else than "index". Example

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<param>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action' => '*your_action*',
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Exactly what I was after. Migrating from CodeIgniter, I'm now starting to see the power of the routing system at play.